# 'flutter run' only runs on flutter projects in home directory

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

I do have an issue which I'm working for a few days on. Many similar issues on StackOverflow and GitHub didn't matched my special case.

I'm building flutter apps and mainly debug them on iOS Simulator (Xcode). It works totally fine and never had an issue which couldn't get solved by litte bit of research.

But now I'm facing a problem that the debugging on iOS Simulator isn't working when the flutter project is located on other directories like OneDrive (for Mac).

Here the Error from Terminal:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            6.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-06-11 01:52:58.729 xcodebuild[29723:234875] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-11 01:52:58.730 xcodebuild[29723:234875] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/3n/66j3dtg939xg3sz7229460w40000gn/T/flutter_tools.o0iQn1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirURZJhA/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Failed to package /Users/abderrahmanecharrade/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/03_Privat/05_Code/03_Flutter/mepcherry.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/3n/66j3dtg939xg3sz7229460w40000gn/T/flutter_tools.o0iQn1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirURZJhA/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
Exited
```

Here the specs of my machine and running apps:

- macOS Monterey 12.4
- Flutter 3.0.1
- Xcode 13.4.1
- Visual Studio Code (Flutter Extension up to date and Code Editor also)
  => Everything is up to date, see 'flutter doctor'

```
❯ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale
    en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Here also a snippet from my ~/.zshrc file. **Maybe the error is here**

```
# Flutter Global Variable
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/usr/webapp-tools/flutter/bin"
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path)
export SDKROOT=$/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
```

Thank you all in advance for every helpful advise

Comment: A couple things that come to my mind:
- `flutter run` is broken on newer versions of Xcode if I remember correctly. I had similar issues and installed Xcode 13.2.1, which worked just fine. You can have multiple versions of Xcode installed at the same time and just have to switch between the command line tools. See xcodereleases.com

Comment: You could also try `flutter run --verbose` to see if you get any more error messages that might be more helpful

Comment: And as a side note: There are other cloud-synchronization services tha might be better suited for your needs than just a plain Onedrive/GoogleDrive/...
You might want to look into Github and git for example

Comment: Hi @JoRa, 

just tried ```flutter run --verbose```. But without a result. Same error message as posted above when hitting ```flutter run```

But thanks anyway.